# BSOD after Windows 8 Update on Macbook Air

Tags: windows-8, bsod, updates, touchpad, macbook-air

Whenever I try to update Windows 8 running dual-boot on my 2012 Macbook Air 13", I get a perpetual blue screen of death after restarting that can only be solved with a System Restore.  According to [this WinSuperSite article](http://winsupersite.com/article/windows-7/macbook-air-windows-7-part-imperfect-storm-135952), the BSOD after updates is caused by the Apple Trackpad drivers.

I have tried disabling Apple Multitouch and Apple Multitouch Mouse under Human Interface Devices before updating, but the problem persists.

How do I update Windows on my Macbook Air without triggering a blue screen?

Comment: upload the dmp files, so that we can look at them with WinDbg

Comment: Looks like Windows deleted the DMP file because I had less than 25GB of space left on my SSD. Any idea to prevent that?

Comment: Windows needs a pagefile. Have you disabled the pagefile?