# Windows 8.1 Pro RTM Update Fails on Macbook Air 2012

Tags: updates, macbook-air, windows-8.1

Updating Windows 8 Pro x64 to 8.1 Pro RTM* fails with error code `0xC000000e` on my 13" Macbook Air 2012 running Windows 8 Pro natively. The Windows 8.1 ISO is located on a secondary Windows partition. Could the location of the ISO be the cause of the error? Should I burn my ISO to a USB for it to work?

I have been unable to install any other Windows updates due to faulty Apple Multitouch drivers as [detailed here](https://superuser.com/q/560103/33450). Buggy Intel GPU drivers are causing my Macbook to crash once or twice per day, but I can't upgrade them due to the Multitouch issue. As a developer this is driving me crazy, so any help would be most appreciated.

*I have early access to Windows 8.1 RTM builds because I am on [BizSpark](http://bizspark.com/). This is not 8.1 Preview.

Yes, I know I'm a masochist for running Windows on a Macbook Air.

[image: Windows 8.1 Failed Update Recovery Screen]

Comment: Just for clarification, as far as I know, Win 8.1 including updates to 8 will not be released for a month. What kind of 8.1 version are you trying to update to? Preview?

Comment: @Zerobinary99 it's RTM, not Preview. I get early developer access to 8.1 through BizSpark. Added clarification to question.

Comment: Is it so crucial to keep your old Windows 8 setup? I'd rather try installing Windows 8.1 natively. If you're using an online account in Windows 8, 8.1 will ask you during setup if you want to import the original settings of 8. This could be a lot less painful than trying to get the update working.

Comment: Yes, if I have to re-install all my Visual Studio updates and  applications, then I would rather not upgrade.

Comment: Well, you can always wait till Microsoft releases the update through Windows Update. May be that will work. In the meantime you can run 8.1 in a virtual machine to test your code. Personally, I use a portable version of Visual Studio so I can easily switch between operating systems without having to re-install it over and over :)

Comment: How do you install Visual Studio as a portable version? Unstable Apple drivers cause a BSOD whenever I try to use Windows Update: http://superuser.com/q/560103/33450

Comment: With lots of patience and VMWare ThinApp :) It works pretty well. I created two versions. One including Net Framework allowing me to use it even on systems that don't have it installed and one without. Everything is neatly packaged into a less than 1GB-sized container. Also, thanks to that, my drive's MFT doesn't get burdened by the 30.000+ file entries Visual Studio unloads on the system. Regarding your Apple drivers, that really sucks. If those are the problem then updating will probably also be impossible when MS rolls out the update officially, so a fresh install is probably unavoidable.

Comment: 0xC000000e = STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE So Windows doesn't find the HDD

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks. Where can we find error references like that?

Comment: I use **err.exe** from Windows 7 SDK to translate error codes.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @overdose no, I don't have a solution yet.